# migration assistant fails to move data files

Tags: migration

Using Migration Assistant, with direct connection by Ethernet, between two Mac Minis, both running Mavericks.All my applications moved, but none of my data files.
Have tried moving my data to various locations on the source computer but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you read the instructions how to migrate on [Mavericks](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872).

There is also the [manual data transfer information here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6101).